# Subtracting Minutes from SYSTIMESTAMP or SYSDATE in H2 not working

Tags: java, oracle, time, timestamp, h2

Subtracting Minutes from SYSTIMESTAMP or SYSDATE in `H2` not working .The result for following two commands are same:

```
select SYSTIMESTAMP from dual;    

select SYSTIMESTAMP- 30 / 1440 from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That math only works for DATE data types (e.g. SYSDATE), not for TIMESTAMP. For TIMESTAMP, use the INTERVAL function:

```
select systimestamp, systimestamp - interval '30' second from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                        SYSTIMESTAMP-INTERVAL'30'SECOND    
----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
13-APR-22 03.34.41.414075000 PM GMT 13-APR-22 03.34.11.414075000 PM GMT
```

See here for a thorough explanation of the differences in the two data types and their operations: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals

H2 doesn't support the same functions as Oracle; use something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD('SECOND',-30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ...
```

Comment: Thanks. And what about SYSDATE  in H2?

Comment: @TohidMakari i updated my answer. it doesn't look like H2 and Oracle share any common date functions or interval logic. Have to use different syntax for each.

Comment: FYI, the [SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) does not specify such date-time functions. So databases vary widely in their features and syntax.